# SQL Autoincrement on Foreign key (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "Address" it reference to the table "Member", 
Address has a column called "id" , this column is a foreignkey. 
I forgot to add a autoincroment on this column.

Member:

- id
- name
- lastname
- ....
- address_id (foreignkey)

Address:

- id (this should be autoincreoment)
- street
- number
- place
- zipcode

when i try in sql

```
ALTER TABLE Address MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment;
```

it throughs an error:

```
Error Code: 1833. Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'fk_Member_Address1' of table 'mydb.member'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to drop the foreign key constraint
Then change the name
and recreate the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fire these queries in sequence:

1. `ALTER TABLE Member DROP FOREIGN KEY` `address_id`;
2. `ALTER TABLE Address MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment;`
3. `ALTER TABLE Member ADD FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES Address(`id`);`

Here you first remove foreign key constraint from member table, then add auto_increment to address table and then again add foreign key constraint to member table.

Hope it helps.